# How do I install CPAN modules while using perlbrew?

Tags: perl, module, version, cpan, perlbrew

I have started using `perlbrew` and installed perl-5.12.2.

I understand I need to re-install my CPAN modules, so I switched to my new Perl version (`perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2` and `hash -r`), verified the switch was successful (`perl -v`) then tried installing some module (`File::Copy::Recursive` using `cpan`. However, `cpan` says `File::Copy::Recursive is up to date (0.38).

When I start a Perl script using this module, it shouts `Can't locate File/Copy/Recursive.pm in @INC ...` (showing many `perl-5.12.2` locations). When I switch back to my 'normal' Perl (`perlbrew off`) the script runs fine.

Any suggestions? Perhaps CPAN does not work well with `perlbrew`?

Answer (score 45):

After installing perlbrew you could install cpanm through this command:

```
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

Otherwise you will need to install cpanm manually each time you switch your Perl version on perlbrew. With this command just once.

Once installed you can then use `cpanm` to install the missing module:

```
cpanm File::Copy::Recursive
```

Comment: Btw., in case you didn't know (as I didn't), cpanm is a cpan alternative, which works better with perlbrew.  After installing as above, then you can use, e.g. "cpanm install File::Copy::Recursive", etc.

Comment: @JoshuaRichardson: Notice `cpanm install` will try to install `install` module. because `cpanm` has not such command: `Usage: cpanm [options] Module [...]`

Answer (score 2):

Everything should be working fine with "cpan" as well as "cpanm", that is: when switching perl with perlbrew, cpan sees the installed modules of the version you use.

While it's true that cpanm is the recommended tool to use with perlbrew, cpan allows for test reporting so that is what I always use.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I install CPAN modules while using perlbrew?

That's how:

```sh
perlbrew use <version>

cpan -i <module>
```

Comment: There is no "install" command to cpan. Just note the modules that you want to install.

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected that, I must have confused the `-i` option for a non-existing `install` subcommand: _-i module [ module ... ]: Install the specified modules. With no other switches, this switch is implied._